# Unable to open Drawer when clicked on Hamburger Icon in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have this nav drawer which was working perfectly fine when clicked on button from render method but how to open when clicked on **Hamburger Icon** from `navigationOptions`. Saw couple of websites but nothing seems to work.

**Partial working expo demo** -> [App Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@sharathm/navigation-drawer)

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from "react-native-paper";
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json

import theme from "./styles/theme";

import HomeScreen from "./src/Home";
import DetailsScreen from "./src/Details";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Details: {
      screen: DetailsScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#6B8E23',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppContainer />
      </PaperProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withTheme  } from "react-native-paper";
import { View, Text, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import { UIIconButton, UIButton } from "../components/index";
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

import BillScreen from "./Bill";
import PaymentScreen from "./Payment";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: "Home",
      headerLeft:
        <UIIconButton
                    icon="menu"
          size={30}
          color="white"
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')}
                />,
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <HomeApp />
    );
  }  
}

HomeScreen.propTypes = {
    theme: PropTypes.object,
};

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Bill: {
        screen: BillScreen,
    },
    Payment: {
        screen: PaymentScreen,
    },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Bill',
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
  drawerType: "slide"
});

const HomeApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);

export default withTheme(HomeScreen);
```

complete source code can be found in the above link mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have disconnected the nesting of your navigators.
By that, I mean that you are rendering your `HomeApp` inside a component that is a screen of your main stack. So your main stack is not having any instance of drawer's navigation object that has the capability for toggling the drawer.

**Edited:** the `navigation` object you are getting from the `navigationOptions` is only for the stack navigator.

What you should do is directly nest your drawer in your stack and make the home screen as the first screen of your drawer navigator.
The code should look like below:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  MyDrawer : {
    screen: MyFancyDrawer,
  },
  Details: {
  screen: DetailsScreen,
  },
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'MyDrawer',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#6B8E23',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
  }
 }
);
```

and your drawer should be:

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
HomeScreen: {
   screen: Home
},
Bill: {
    screen: BillScreen,
},
Payment: {
    screen: PaymentScreen,
},
});
```

Although then your Home should be a stack in itself first as there is no default `header` option in `navigationOption` for drawer navigator. or if not want to make Home as yet another stack, then directly make your header as a custom component in the `render()` of Home.